# Not getting a [:id] parameter from url, Default route is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, routes, url-parameters

When I request a URL as follows:

`http://localhost:3000/password_resets/edit/4RghIKJNygEDswIuuCo`

I'm not getting the `[:id]` parameter, i.e. **4RghIKJNygEDswIuuCo**.

Here is my route file, are there any modifications required for this?

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  match 'primary', :to => 'pages#primary', :as => "primary"
  match 'admins', :to => 'admin_users#list', :as => "admins"

  match 'login', :to => 'user_sessions#new', :as => "login"
  match 'logout', :to => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => "logout"

  root :to =>"public#index"

  match 'HFA/:id/' => 'public#show'
  match 'HFA/:id/:uid' =>'public#show'
  match 'public/projectview/:projectid/' => 'public#projectview'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

  resources :users
  resources :usertypes
  resources :user_sessions
end
```

Comment: Does `:id` work when passed in as something purely numerical? I vaguely recall that it has some default assumptions placed on it but I could be wrong.

Comment: show me result of rake routes command and related controllers code.

Answer (score 1):

The default is `/controller/:id/edit`, following the REST architecture.

Do you really want to change this?

If so, verify the order of the declarations:

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

and check your availables routes with the `rake routes` command:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes

Answer (score 0):

if you put match instead of 'get' you will get all http (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) route verbs

```
 get 'password_resets/:id/edit', to: 'password_reset#create', as: :send_password_reset
```

the 'to:' defines the controller method, 'as:' defines the path name, 'get' defines the route verb and ':id' is the token created by this line in app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb

```
<%= send_password_reset_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

run "rake routes" command and check the routes for "password_resets/edit/4RghIKJNygEDswIuuCo".

Comment: Is this an answer, or a request for more data? At any rate, the output of `rake routes` would look more like `password_resets/edit/[:id]`. If resource routing was set up, it might look more like `password_resets/[:id]/edit` anyway.